# no p_signature in Laravel paddle

Tags: php, laravel

I am quiet new in Laravel. and trying to integrate paddle in Laravel Application. but 403 error is thrown. and it is written "Invalid Signature". When I tried to debug more. I found out that no p_signature is found. It is just empty space.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $fields = $this->extractFields($request);
    $signature = base64_decode($request->get(self::SIGNATURE_KEY));
    if ($this->isInvalidSignature($fields, $signature)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Invalid webhook signature.');
    }
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

What is the problem in the above method?

Comment: Can you include the extractFields() method in your question?

Answer (score 1):

It is because paddle is now creating by default billing accounts, instead of classic accounts, and you're following classic accounts documentation,

In paddle Billing account you will get signature in the `Paddle-Signature`

do like this, you will get signature

```
 $signature = $request->header('Paddle-Signature');
```